# Pytest Unit Testing API's best practice and dependencies

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using pytest to test various API's I have created and was curious on some best practices as my tests are getting more complicated in a sense that some api's depend on the creation of others. Example below.

Lets say I have a service that creates purchase-orders, each purchase-order can have multiple line-items.

My `POST /api/purchase-orders/line-item` takes a body like below.

```
{
  "service_order_id": 0,
  "part_id": 0,
  "vendor_id": 0,
  "component": {
    "component_serial_number": "Test",
    "component_name": "Test",
  },
  "part_description": "Test",
  "total_qty": 1,
}
```

Before I can create a line-item, you can see that I need a part_id, a service_order_id, and a vendor_id. These can be created and fetched using the relative POST/GET methods for those domains.

My question is when unit-testing `POST /api/purchase-orders/line-item` what would we best practice. Should I within a function called `test_line_item_creation` first create the object of vendor, part, service-order, send the appropriate POST requests for each, fetch the id's back and then plug them into my line-item payload. Or should I have separate test files and functions for those domains which create their own objects using their relative api's and inject the response from those domains into this function?

What would be considered best practice? Is what I am even doing considered unit-testing, is pytest the best tool for this type of testing?

Comment: For a unit test, you can hard-cod the parameters. The purpose is to observe how a given `POST` request is *handled*, regardless of how it was created. To do this, you may need an appropriately initialized server, but how you do *that* is independent of the test itself.

Comment: @chepner Hmmm I am not sure I agree on hard-coding the id's. Yes I have a server where I know of some legitimate id's for vendor/part. But later on those id's can be deleted or change. If I then continue to use those id's as part of this payload this request will most likely error out and the test will fail due to key constraints on the database side.

Comment: As far as a *unit test* is concerned, changed IDs indicate a failure to use an appropriate text fixture where the valid IDs are known. Testing against a live database is more of an *integration test* (or maybe an even higher level of testing; see https://reqtest.com/en/knowledgebase/different-levels-of-testing/ for example).